# Making dynamically generated buttons hidden by default

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, onclick

I'm making a webpage and what I have is that I'm getting names from my database, which are then made into buttons. The buttons have an onclick function that works fine (it hides the content of whatever button I press) but all content is visible by default, which is not what I want.

'display: none' isn't working for me for some reason. Am I missing something here?

The HTML:

```
  <h3>Select Class:  </h3>
    <ul>
            <?php
            $count = 0;
                while($getName = mysqli_fetch_assoc($un)){
                        $name = $record['Name'];
                        $count++;
                        echo "<div id = 'classes'><button class = 'classes' onclick = 'toggleCont($count)'>".$name."</button></div>";
                        echo "<div id = '$count'><div class = 'content'>"DETAILS HERE"</div></div>";
                    }
        ?>
  </ul>
```

---

The CSS

```
    #classes{
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: auto;
  height: 10%;
  background-color:#d3dded;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.classes {
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#d3dded;
}

.content{
  width: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 25%;
  display: block;
}
```

---

Finally, the javascript part:

```
<body>
<script>

function toggleCont(name){
    var x = document.getElementById(name);
    if (x.style.display == 'none'){
        x.style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

---

edited code but still isn't working

```
    <script>

function toggleCont(name){
    var x = document.getElementById(name);
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("display");
    if (style == 'none') {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
</script> 
    <?php
            $count = 0;
                while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($un)){
                        $count++;
                        $class = 'content'.$count;
                        echo "<div class = 'btnclasses'><button class = 'classes' onclick = 'toggleCont($class)'>".$record['un']."</button></div>";
                        echo "<div id = '$class' class = 'content'>".$record['un']."</div>";
                    }
        ?>
```

css

```
    .btnclasses{
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: auto;
  height: 10%;
  background-color:#d3dded;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.classes {
  padding: 20px;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#d3dded;
}

.content{
  width: auto;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 25%;
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS style rules aren't visible to JavaScript until you apply them with JavaScript. You need to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the rule value:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("display");

if (style == 'none') {
    x.style.display = "block";
} else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
}
```